# Exact algorithm for the partition problem

Tags: optimization, partitions

The [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) is: given a set of numbers, find a partition to two subsets in which the difference between the sums in each subset is minimized. This optimization problem is NP-hard. The simple exact algorithm - checking all the possible partitions - takes time $O(n 2^n)$. Is there a more efficient exact algorithm?

NOTE: If the numbers are small integers, then it can be solved by a pseudo-polynomial algorithm, but I am interested in a problem with real numbers (e.g. "double"s in Java).

Comment: Are you looking for theoretical or practical algorithms? For the latter, see https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0004370298000861/1-s2.0-S0004370298000861-main.pdf?_tid=06fbef54-d221-11e7-9c90-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1511642675_4f8a9ccac43c73c77941e7f796b41437.